# Count number of arbitrary repeating decimal numbers in NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, numbers, nsnumber

In my code, I'm dealing with an NSString that contains an NSNumber value. This NSNumber value could **possibly** be a repeating decimal number (e.x. 2.333333333e+06) that shortens to "2.333333" in a string format. It could also be a terminating number (e.x. 2.5), negative, or irrational number (2.398571892858...) (only dealing with decimals here)

I need to have a way to figure out if there are the repeating numbers in the string (or the NSNumber, if necessary). In my code, I would have no way to know what the repeating number would be, as it's a result of computations started by the user. I have tried this `for` loop (see below) that doesn't work the way I want it to, due to my inexperience with string indexing/ranges/lengths.

```
BOOL repeat = NO; //bool to check if repeating #
double repNum, tempNum; //run in for loop
NSString *repeating = [numVal stringValue]; //string that holds possible repeating #
for (int i = 3; i <= [repeating length]-3; i++) { //not sure about index/length here
            if (i == 3) {
                  repNum = [repeating characterAtIndex:i];
                    }
            tempNum = [repeating characterAtIndex:i];
            if (tempNum == repNum) {
                     repeat = YES;
                      } else {
                        repeat = NO;
                    }

                }
```

This code doesn't work as I'd like it to, mainly because I also have to account for negative dashes in the string and different amounts of numbers (13 1/3 vs. 1 1/3). I've used the `modf`function to separate the integers from the decimals, but that hasn't worked well for me either.

Thank you in advance. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

**EDIT**:

This code works with the finding of different solutions for polynomials (quadratic formula). Hope this helps put it into context. See here. (Example input)

```
NSNumber *firstPlusSolution, *secondMinusSolution;
NSString *pValueStr, *mValueStr;

firstPlusSolution = -(b) + sqrt(square(b) - (4)*(a)*(c)); //a, b, c: "user" provided
firstPlusSolution /= 2*(a);

secondMinusSolution = -(b) - sqrt(square(b) - 4*(a)*(c));
secondMinusSolution /= 2*(a);

pValueStr = [firstPlusSolution stringValue];
mValueStr = [secondMinusSolution stringValue];

if ([NSString doesString:pValueStr containCharacter:'.']) { //category method I implemented

    double fractionPart, integerPart;
    fractionPart = modf(firstPlusSolution, &integerPart);

    NSString *repeating = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", fractionPart];
    int repNum, tempNum;
    BOOL repeat = NO;

   //do for loop and check for negatives, integers, etc.
}

if ([NSString doesString:mValueStr containCharacter'.']) { 
   //do above code
   //do for loop and check again    
}
```

Comment: How does "2.333333333e+06" shorten to "2.333333"? The process is unclear

Comment: Also, do you wish to check for repeating numbers *anywhere* in your string (that's what your question title suggests)? Like for instance, 22222.3 and 2.33333 ?

Comment: @user2311023 On 1st comment, that's what it does. The transfer from NSNumber to NSString shortens it (at least for me) to 2.33333. I assumed that's just part of the casting of the value to another object. 2nd comment: No, sorry, just the decimal. Will edit to make more clear.

Comment: You don't fully understand the mathematical concept of "repeating number".  Just because a number ends with "67676767" does not mean it's "repeating" in the mathematical sense.  It could be, or the next digit could be 4.  There is no way to examine decimal fraction and tell if it's "repeating" -- to determine if it's "repeating" you must examine the algorithm producing the number.

Comment: See this Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not that far yet. In the confinement of my application, there wouldn't be a possibility for a "6/99" to get a ".06060606" or anything of that nature. I'm only looking at 1-digit repeating numbers at this point. But yes, that will have to be tackled eventually.

Comment: You don't understand.  Simply discovering that the known digits of a decimal fraction repeat says nothing.  33333/10000 = 3.3333.  But that's not a "repeating" number in the mathematical sense, since the next digit is 0.  10/3 also equals 3.3333, to the same precision, but the next digit (and every one after) will also be 3.  As a string, though, you can't tell "3.3333" from "3.3333".

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're saying. Would it be appropriate then, in an application, to display a number (even if it is truly repeating, such as 2/3 = 3.3333333...) as a decimal, and not a fraction (2/3)? That's the only functionality this code is trying to produce.

Comment: Then consider that the number 5.9999.. repeated will round to 6.0.  Every "non-repeating" number is possibly a "repeating" number ending with 99999...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47688/discussion-between-hunter-e-and-hot-licks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use C. Take the fractional part. Convert to a string with a known accuracy. If length of string indicates that last digits are missing, then it does not repeat. Use NSString-UTF8String to convert a string. Get rid of the last digit (may be rounding or actual floating point arithmetic error). Use function int strncmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t num ) to perform comparison within the string itself. If the result is 8 characters long and the last 2 characters match the first 2 characters, then shall the first 6 characters be considered repeating?

Assuming that fraction knowledge your desire:

• Possibility 1: Use fractions. Input fractions. Compute with fractions. Output fractions. Expand upon one of the many examples of a c++ fraction class if necessary and use it.

• Possibility 2: Choose an accuracy which is much less than double. Make a fraction from the result. Reduce the fraction allowing rounding based upon accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use not optimal but easy to write solution

Create `NSMutableDictionary` that will contain number as key and count of occurrence as value.

You can use [componentsSeparatedByString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) if numbers in string delimited by known symbol

In loop check `valueForKey` in dictionary and if need increase value

Last step is analyzing our dictionary and do anything you need with numbers

Comment: How would I go about getting the numbers/occurrences into a dictionary? That's my real issue. I could deal with the occurrence count if I had a way to get the count of arbitrary characters in the string.

Comment: please provide real input example

Comment: Ah-hah! So I know that the repeating #s would be separated by a period. That will work! How would I check occurrence, though? That's still an issue. I updated the question to add context.

Comment: Determining that the known digits repeat does not establish the number as "repeating".